# PHP Socket Client only sends and receives one message

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, udp

I recently started learning php socket.
I want to create a Permanent TCP connection Between server and client! But my PHP Socket Client only sends and receives one message. I want to send and receive messages indefinitely, Through one connection.

Server.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', '8088') or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

while(true) {
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 2048) or die("Could not read input\n");

echo base64_encode($input)."\r\n";

$output="OK";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");

//socket_close($spawn);
//socket_close($socket);
}
?>
```

Client.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$input="Hi";
$socket2 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result2 = socket_connect($socket2, '127.0.0.1', '8088') or die("Could not connect to server\n");
while(true) {
socket_write($socket2, $input, strlen($input)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
$result2 = socket_read ($socket2, 2048) or die("Could not read server response\n");
$output=$result2;
echo $output;
sleep(2);
}

//socket_close($spawn);
//socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In server.php, you need to add another `while(trur) {}` for the code after `socket_accept`, cause if you everytime you run `socket_accept`, the last connection made would not work anymore.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', '8088') or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

while(true) {
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    while(true) {
        $input = socket_read($spawn, 2048) or die("Could not read input\n");

        echo base64_encode($input)."\r\n";

        $output="OK";
        socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
    }
}
//socket_close($spawn);
//socket_close($socket);
```